# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PreviewController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I don't know why I am getting this error.
The error I am getting is Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PreviewController' is not a function, got undefined.
Can someone help me out with this?
Also is there any other way to inject services in a controller?

My code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('MyModule')
        .controller('PreviewController' ['$scope','Service1','Service2', 


    function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/30e2a")
    .success(function(response) {
                                    //Dummy data taken from JSON file
                                    $scope.firstName = response.firstName;
                                    $scope.lastName = response.lastName;
                                    $scope.dateAdded = response.dateAdded;


                                });

    //Functions have been defined. Functionality to be added.

    $scope.cancelAndBack = function() {
                        window.history.back();
    };


}]);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining you module incorrectly.

```
 `angular.module('MyModule')`
```

Is looking for an already initialised module called 'MyModule'.
If you are creating a module from scratch you need to empty array. This would be more module dependencies.

```
`angular.module('MyModule', [])`
```

This is how angular knows the difference between, 'create an app' and 'get me an app'.

Finally services. Your using angulars array notation. That is so you can minify your javascript.

angularjs injection system works by name, that's how it can find the dependencies your require, that's also why you can list them in any order you like. However minifying your code changes your variable names and so breaks angular's injection.

The solution is to provide an array of strings telling angular the services you wish to inject and the order they are injected in.

So your array values and properties passed into your controller function must match.

Correct:

```
.controller('test', ["$scope", "$http", "myService", function( $scope, $http, myService){}]);
```

Incorrect: (`myService` won't be defined as its missing from the array)

```
.controller('test', ["$scope", "$http", function( $scope, $http, myService){}]);
```

Comment: I actually have a module which is defined elsewhere

Comment: My Bad, I found my own mistake... I was missing a comma.. Sorry folks :|

Comment: Maybe that should be mentioned? What is the order of loading? EDIT, ok NP